# Getting a list of elements by using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver

I am attempting to obtain the differents sports that are highlighted on a bookmaker's betting page in order to extract later on the different odds and compare them with other bookmaker's pages.
The inspect result is shown on the picture.
[image]
The code I tried is the following :

sport_list = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "filters__content")

for sport in sport_list:

print(sport.text)

Unfortunately sport_list is only composed of one element why I would expect it to have the same number of elements than the number of sports visible in the inspect section.

It loops only 1 time and returns the following : " Soccer\nTennis\nBasketball\nAmericanFootball ..."

Can someone help me figure out what is going wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Brieuc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What happens?

Cause you are selecting the `<div>` that contains the list you get an resultset with one element (`<div>`) only.

```
driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "filters__content")
```

#### How to fix?

Selecting the `<li>`s in `<div>` and get its text use `xpath` or as in following example `css selectors`.

```
for e in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.filters__content li'):
    print(e.text)
```

#### Output

```
Football
Tennis
Basketball
Football Américain
Hockey sur glace
Esports
Volleyball
Handball
Boxe
Rugby
Snooker
Fléchettes
Cyclisme
Waterpolo
MMA
Stock Car Racing
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sport_list = driver.find_elements(BY.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'filters__content')]//li")
```